# Using an integer parameter in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Is it possible to convert an integer SEXP parameter to an integer directly without first converting it to an integer vector?

Example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

SEXP f(SEXP n)
{
    Rcpp::IntegerVector n_vec(n);
    int n1 = n_vec[0];
    ...
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

Comment: may be with `int n1 = Rcpp::as<int>(n)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course -- the `as<>()` converter does this.

It can be called explicitly (which you need here), is sometimes called implicitly by the compiler, or even inserted by code generation helpers like this:

```
R> cppFunction('int twiceTheValue(int a) { return 2*a; }')
R> twiceTheValue(21)
[1] 42
R>
```

If you call `cppFunction()` (and the related functions from Rcpp attributes, or the inline package) with the `verbose=TRUE` argument, you see the generated code.

Here, I get

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_47500_twiceTheValue(SEXP aSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
    int a = Rcpp::as<int >(aSEXP);
    int __result = twiceTheValue(a);
    return Rcpp::wrap(__result);
END_RCPP
}
```

and our documentation explains what the `BEGIN_RCPP`, `END_RCPP` macros do, why the `RNGScope` object is there -- and you see the `as<>()` and `wrap()` you needed.

Comment: No problem. It's front and center in our documentation (eg the Rcpp-introduction vignette and paper) as well should you choose to read it ;-)